# React-Native FlatList get data with keyExtractor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to change flatlist item data with keyExtractor key

How can i do this?

messages type and flatlist are here

```
messages:[{
        'senderID': data.senderID,
        'messageID' : data.messageID,
        'message': data.message,
        'uri':data.uri,
        'type':data.type,                                
         'date':data.date}]


 <FlatList  style={styles.allmessagesContainer}
                ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}           
                data={this.state.messages}           
                renderItem={({item, index})=>(
                    <View>
                        {item.senderID != this.state.userID ?  
                        <View style={styles.othermessageContainer} >
                        {item.type == "text" ? <Text style={styles.othermessageText}>{item.message}</Text> :
                    </View>

            )}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.messageID.toString()}
            extraData={this.state}
                />
```

Comment: Can you paste the value of `this.state.messages`?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by "I would like to change flatlist item data with keyExtractor key"? For the time being you set the key equal to  item.messageID.toString(). What data you want to change?